# nearZeroVar() CARET Package, Imbalanced classification Data

Tags: r, classification, r-caret

minority class is two percent in the data that i am working on, the number of features are 150, i am using `nearZeroVar()` from CARET package to reduce the number of variable i.e remove uninformative variables, but the procedure removes the dependent variable too. should subset the dependent variable and apply the function on the rest of the data and cbind it later. is that the right way?

Comment: I do not think this function can help you. Many informative features will be removed due to imbalance. And yes, apply  the function only on dependant variables.

Comment: @missuse thanks a lot, btw u mean independent right? would functions like WOE and IV from the information value be helpful?

Comment: Yes I did mean independent. You may attempt filter methods for feature selection. But be careful, if you apply it on the whole data prior to training this will lead to positive bias (optimistic results in cross validation). Suggested reads: [mlr fs](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/feature_selection/index.html) and [nested re-sampling](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/devel/html/nested_resampling/index.html)